# HTML plugin with text right alignment flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using HTML widget from flutter_html library to show some articles fetched from some api and I want to align my text to the right (rtl language)
[image: My Pic]
This my code

```
                      Html(
                        data: widget.article.postContent,
                        defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: ThemeColors.white100,
                        ),
                      ),
```

I have tried to use Directionality widget as parent widget but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

add  customTextAlign property with flutter TextAlign class properties to the widget like the below code

```
 Html(
   customTextAlign: (_) => TextAlign.right,
 ),
```

**UPDATE:**

after version **1.0.0**
it should be like this

```
 Html(
   style: {
     'html': Style(textAlign: TextAlign.right),
    },
 )
```

as mentioned by [MSpeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106941/mspeed)
in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66316735/7060714)

Answer (score 9):

It seems like the other answer might be out of date now. I had luck with this:

```
 Html(
   data: myData,
   style: {
     'html': Style(textAlign: TextAlign.center)
    },
 )
```